# VirtualBox: create image of bootable flash disk

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, image

I have a bootable flash disk which I want to use as a boot disk for my virtual machine. How do I make a virtual hard drive file out of the flash disk?

Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Try

dd if=/dev/< flash disk >  of=image.iso

Comment: ...assuming linux or other unix-like, of course.

Comment: I tried both /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb1, the resulting ISOs are neither mountable nor bootable.